# How to understand the "calculate the priors based on occurence in the training set" in the function

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, bayesian

I have a function from a toolbox, I paste it here. I cannot understand the last part,
which begins from "**`% // calculate the priors based on occurence in the training set`**" ? Can
anybody explain it for me? Thank you so much!

```
function [scratch] = train_gnb(trainpats,traintargs, in_args, cv_args)

% // Use a Gaussian Naive Bayes classifier to learn regressors.
%
% // [SCRATCH] = TRAIN_GNB(TRAINPATS, TRAINTARGS, IN_ARGS, CV_ARGS)
%
% // The Gaussian Naive Bayes classifier makes the assumption that
% // each data point is conditionally independent of the others, given
% // a class label, and that, furthermore, the likelihood function for
% // each class is normal.  The likelihood of a given data point X,
% // where Y is one of K labels, is thus:
%
% // Pr ( X | Y==K) = Product_N ( Normal(X_N | theta_K) ) 
% 
% // The GNB is trained by finding the Normal MLE's for each subset of
% // the training set that have the same label.  Each voxel has a
% // scalar mean and a scalar variance.
%
% // OPTIONAL ARGUMENTS:
%
% // UNIFORM_PRIOR (default = true): If uniform_prior is true,
% // then the algorithm will assume that no classes are
% // inherently more likely than others, and will use 1/K as
% // the prior probability for each of K classes.  If
% // uniform_prior is false, then train_gnb will estimate the
% // priors from the data using laplace smoothing: if N_k is
% // the number of times class k is observed in the training
% // set and N is the total number of training datapoints, then
% // Pr(Y == k) = (N_k + 1) / (N + K).  This way, no cluster is
% // ever assigned a 0 prior.

% // License:
% // =====================================================================
%
% // This is part of the Princeton MVPA toolbox, released under
% // the GPL. See http://www.csbmb.princeton.edu/mvpa for more
% // information.
% 
%  // The Princeton MVPA toolbox is available free and
% // unsupported to those who might find it useful. We do not
% // take any responsibility whatsoever for any problems that
% // you have related to the use of the MVPA toolbox.
%
% // ======================================================================

defaults.uniform_prior = true;

args = mergestructs(in_args, defaults);

nConds = size(traintargs,1);
[nVox nTimepoints] = size(trainpats);

% // find a gaussian distribution for each voxel for each category

scratch.mu = NaN(nVox, nConds);
scratch.sigma = NaN(nVox, nConds);

for k = 1:nConds

  % // grab the subset of the data with a label of category k
    k_idx = find(traintargs(k, :) == 1);

    if numel(k_idx) < 1
      error('Condition %g has no data points.', k);
    end

    data = trainpats(:, k_idx);

    % calculate the maximum likelihood estimators (mean and variance)
    [ mu_hat, sigma_hat] = normfit(data');

    scratch.mu(:,k) = mu_hat;
    scratch.sigma(:,k) = sigma_hat;

end

% // calculate the priors based on occurence in the training set
scratch.prior = NaN(nConds, 1);
if (args.uniform_prior)
  scratch.prior = ones(nConds,1) / nConds;
else

  for k = 1:nConds  
    scratch.prior(k) = (1 + numel( find(traintargs(k, :) == 1))) / ...
        (nConds + nTimepoints);    
  end

end
```

Comment: why deduct 1 points?

Comment: Because, as written, the question does not appear to be a programming question.  It appears to be more like a question about prior distributions, which is not really a Matlab question.  Perhaps adding additional explanation about what you do and do not understand about this code would let people see where your trouble is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "prior" is the "prior distribution", which is the distribution describing the likelihood of each class.  This is relevant when it comes time to look at a new data point and, based on your training data, to decide which class it is.  If you know a priori that one class is more likely to occur than another class, it will affect the decision on the class to which the new point belongs.

A common assumption for the prior distribution  is a "uniform prior" which means that, when you go to test a new data point, we assume that each class is as like as likely to occur as any other class.  A uniform prior is a good assumption, but may not model the data very well.

A better model would be to assume that your training data is a good representation of all data.  You then measure the distribution of each class in your training data.  This becomes your prior.

So, back to your example code, your question is about the section of code that defines the prior.  This section of code is described in the block comments at the top of your code.  See the section that reads:

```
% UNIFORM_PRIOR (default = true): If uniform_prior is true,
% then the algorithm will assume that no classes are
% inherently more likely than others, and will use 1/K as
% the prior probability for each of K classes.  If
% uniform_prior is false, then train_gnb will estimate the
% priors from the data using laplace smoothing: if N_k is
% the number of times class k is observed in the training
% set and N is the total number of training datapoints, then
% Pr(Y == k) = (N_k + 1) / (N + K).  This way, no cluster is
% ever assigned a 0 prior.
```

In the code itself, you see the initial `if (args.uniform_prior)` which determines whether you're assuming the uniform prior or not....

If you *are* assuming a uniform prior, then the line `scratch.prior = ones(nConds,1) / nConds;` sets the prior to all the same value...ie, a uniform distribution.  Apparently the number of classes is defined by `nConds` so that the likelihood of a new data point being in any one class is basically `1 / nConds`.

If you are *not* assuming a uniform prior, the `for` loop goes through your training data and counts the number of occurrences of each class...via the portion of the line `numel( find(traintargs(k, :) == 1))`.  The rest of this line of code normalizes and smooths this value, using (I guess) the laplace smoothing technique discussed in the block comment at the top.

I hope that this helps!

Chip

Comment: I want to modify this train_gnb function. I can understand the part before "prior". I want to use it to apply to real data. And the "prior distribution" is the part I cannot understand and do not know how to modify it to fit for real data. As you said :"It is a uniform prior is a good assumption, but may not model the data very well." Can you tell me is there any other more understandable ways to realize it?

Comment: If I want to use this function, I have to create subj fit for every function in the toolbox. But I just want to modify this function and make it independent of other functions in MVPA toolbox. Just want to train my own data

Comment: Regarding your first question, if you are not going to assume a uniform prior, and if you are not going to use the laplace-smoothed version, you could time the raw, unsmoothed distribution from your training data.  In the `for` loop, you might do something like `scratch.prior(k) = numel( find(traintargs(k, :) == 1)) / total_number_of_data_points;`

Comment: As for your 2nd question, I don't know what you mean by " I have to create subj fit for every function in the toolbox".  What's a "subj fit".  I don't know about the MVPA toolbox...so if your problem is something with the toolbox itself, I can't help you.

Comment: this function is connected with other functions. I want to make this function to be an independent one. That means write a general code, not a function, but realize the purpose of this function. That is my purpose to modify this code.

Comment: If this is your goal, please return to your original post and edit it to add material describing how you have tried to make it a stand-alone function.  Show your new code such as your new function name and your function arguments.  In your new code, point out which specific locations you are having difficulty.  By adding material to your original post in this way, you are most likely to receive the help that you want.